# R: How to retrieve corpus from a list of elements returned by a function?

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, text-analysis, quanteda

I am processing multiple large text documents. Therefore I wish to use function to process each of them. A sample function looks like below:

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(quanteda)

txtOverview<-function(x){

  txt_file<-x
  txt_size<-object.size(txt_file) #Getting text size
  txt_file_ascii<-stri_trans_general(txt_file,"latin-ascii") 
  txt_stats<-stri_stats_general(txt_file_ascii) 
  txt_words<-stringr::str_count(txt_file_ascii,"\\S+")
  txt_words<-sum(txt_words)
  txt_corpus<-corpus(txt_file_ascii) 
  txt_corpus<-corpus_reshape(txt_corpus) 
  corpus_list<-c("txt_size"=txt_size,"lines"=txt_stats[1],"words"=txt_words,"characters"=txt_stats[3],"corpus"=txt_corpus)
  return(corpus_list)
}
```

Then I call the function:

```
test_txt1<-c("here is an example", "I am trying to learn corpus", "Why would a function return an integer?")
test_txt2<-c("sky is blue", "orange is orange", "why do chickens want to cross the road?")
test_txt3<-c("lunch was ok", "carbon hydrates taste good", "Why would lasagna have six layers?")
x<-txtOverview(test_txt1)
y<-txtOverview(test_txt2)
z<-txtOverview(test_txt3)
```

I will then want to extract the corpus from each list and then combine them using Quanteda. After looking at x, I figured that x[5] or x$corpus.documents is the texts part. However, there are also `"corpus.metadata",  "corpus.settings"`
and `"corpus.tokens"`. Trying the ling below

```
w<-x[5]+y[5]+z[5]
```

would return error

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: the `+` operator is probably not defined for your objects,; they are not numeric? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to combine the corpora from the lists of x, y and z. I read from here http://docs.quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/quickstart.html that when using Quanteda, you can directly add two corpora together to create the third corpus. But I could be horribly wrong and now it seems very likely that I am.

Comment: what is `class(x[5]`, or `str(x[5])` you probably want to use `c()` to combine if they are vectors, or `rbind()` if they are dataframes. `+` is only defined for particular data structures and types. I have not used `quanteda` but not having the right type is what the error message points towards. Perhaps also try `x[[5]] + y[[5]]`.

Comment: `class(x[5])` is data.frame. I need to retrieve the corpus from the returned list of elements from the function. However, it seems to be a problem, because the corpus includes four elements.

Comment: This is needlessly complicated, both in terms of mixing objects of different types, and in trying to understand what it outputs. Try to focus on the following: Create a named character vector of texts, with a unique document name as the element names. Create a corpus from that. Add a data.frame of document variables, with each row corresponding to one document, using `docvars(yourcorpus) <-`. These can be the summary stats you are computing in the function, although **quanteda** offers some of these, e.g. `ntoken()`.

Comment: Also I highly recommend spending some time with http://style.tidyverse.org.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on learning R styling. I just read some and immediately realized that I made the mistakes of having underscores in my function names.  When you said "This is needlessly complicated, both in terms of mixing objects of different types, and in trying to understand what it outputs. ", do you mean that I should not have used function. Instead I should just directly do the steps? Sorry I didn't quite understand the purpose of using `docvars(yourcorpus)` . Should I use `sapply() ` instead? But even so it seems that I would still need to repeat codes...